# Android full screen tablet app

Tags: android

I want to display android app in full screen for tablets.

I thought of using `view.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);` to hide navigation but the problem is that I have buttons in my view. If I hide navigation like this, every time user want's to click butto, on first click the menu shows up but the button isn't clicked.

I wouldn't care if the menu shows or not after click but I don't want users to ask to click twice to choose something.

What would be the suggested way to display my app in full screen?

Comment: I would reconsider this idea. Few apps really need to be in full screen.

Comment: Did you tried this.requestWindowFeature((int)Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this code:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Edit your Manifest.xml file:
Use this code if you want to display all the Activities in Full Screen Mode:

```
<application 
android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
...
</application>
```

Use this code if you want to display some Activities in Full Screen Mode:

```
<activity
android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
...
</activity>
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this line in Activity on onCreate method :

```
this.requestWindowFeature((int)Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION will cause those navigation controls to just disappear.There is a limitation: because navigation controls are so important, the least user interaction will cause them to reappear immediately.